# How to update datetime regularly?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, time, clock

I want to print out the datetime every second. When I ran

```
import time, datetime

t0 = time.time()

while True:
    print (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.localtime(t0)))
    time.sleep(1)
```

I expected to see this

```
20:58:30
20:58:31
20:58:32
20:58:33
20:58:34
```

etc. But I got this instead:

```
20:58:30
20:58:30
20:58:30
20:58:30
20:58:30
```

How do I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time, datetime

while True:
    t0 = time.time()
    print (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.localtime(t0)))
    time.sleep(1)
```

In case you want that the update occurs at the same line:

```
while True:
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.localtime(time.time())))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm relatively new to programming but I wanted to share what I figured out.

I had the same problem. I was trying to update a database with a timestamp of Last_modified using the datetime class. The result of my call to datetime  would always return the same result which was undesirable.

Here's what worked for me:

```
import time
cur_time = time.localtime()
```

The variable cur_time now has properties that pertain to right now.

So, now you can get properties e.g.;

```
hour = cur_time.tm_hour
minute = cur_time.tm_min
```

Hope this helps